# Configure postfix with inbound authentication

Tags: email, authentication, postfix-mta

I want to configure postfix with inbound authentication.
For example, if this is my list of clients:

```
user             |    password

alice@alice.com          1234
bob@bob.com              5678
```

I want to serve only them and accept connections only from them.

The use-case is: Alice wants to send a mail to someone@gmail.com and pass through my MTA.
Alice opens a connection to my postfix (MAIL FROM: alice@alice.com, RCPT TO: someone@gmail.com),
and somewhere in the middle I want Alice to identify with her password 1234.

How can I force it using postfix configurations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`

master.cf:

```
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=auth
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = auth
auth = permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

These snippets are just very basic examples. Please read the [Postfix Documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) to get an idea how the authentication works.